# jQuery sortable pushes content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've added the sortable jQuery plugin but I'm having this weird effect when I drag an item everything else is pushed down a bit.

I'm not really sure why this is, and it makes it hard for me to inspect the elements when I have to hold the mousebutton down.

Though I did try with the only css being:

```
#link_boxes li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and that didn't help at all. Anyway, here is the full code:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="link_boxes">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div style="background-image: url('http://.../images/blue_aid.jpg')"></div>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Hearing Aid Prices</h4>
                <span class="label label-default">/prices</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div style="background-image: url('http://.../images/audiologist-02.jpg')"></div>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Special Offers</h4>
                <span class="label label-default">/link1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#link_boxes li {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#link_boxes .thumbnail {
    width: 194px;
    margin:  0 14px 0 0;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

#link_boxes .thumbnail > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

#link_boxes .thumbnail span {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#link_boxes .thumbnail .caption {
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link_boxes").sortable();
    $("#link_boxes").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
vertical-align:top;
```

to you #link_boxes li, jquery sortable got problem with vertical-align. According to this answer: [sortable vertical align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095451/jsquery-sortable-with-inline-block-display-display-scratches)